# Deprecated Warning: safeHtml

Tags: craft3, plugin-embeddedassets

I'm getting a Deprecated Warning on the property safeHtml:

> The embedded asset property `safeHtml` is now deprecated. Use a
>   combination of the `isSafe()` method and the `code` property instead.

This is picked up on line 4 and 11 of the code below:

```
        {# if video embed #}
        {% if embed.type == 'video' %}
            <div class="aspect-ratio aspect-ratio--16x9">
                {% set vidcode = embed.isSafe() | trim('<iframe') %}
                {% set vid = '<iframe class="aspect-ratio--object" ' ~ vidcode %}
                {{ vid|raw }}
            </div>
        {# else if rich embed #}
        {% else %}
            <div class="w-100 w-75-ns center">
                {{ embed.isSafe()|raw }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
```

How do I update this code correctly to remove the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you are using Craft CMS 3, you can try the [`purify`](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#purify) filter.

In your code, change this line:

```
{% set vidcode = embed.isSafe() | trim('<iframe') %}
```

To something like:

```
{% set vidcode = embed | purify | trim('<iframe') %}
```

Documentation: